# Gradle - Java compile ignoring non-java source files

Tags: java, compilation, gradle

I have some .properties files along with .java files in the java project. When Gradle compiles it seems to be only taking .class file and ignoring the .properties files & .csv files while making the jar.

Can anyone let us know how to get the .properties files, .csv files also gets compiled into the classes folder?

For example, if my project has the following files,

```
"src/main/java/com/spcapitaliq/test/Test.java"
"src/main/java/com/spcapitaliq/test/Test.properties"
"src/main/java/com/spcapitaliq/test/Test.csv"
```

I am seeing only the Test.class in the classes folder not the Test.properties & Test.csv files. Can you let me know how to include the .properties files & .csv files during the gradle compilation process. In eclipse, its bringing both but gradle compile is ignoring that.

The following is my  SourceSet entry in "gradle.build" file,

```
sourceSets
    {
        main
        {
            java
            {
                srcDir 'src/main/java’
            }
            resources
            {
                srcDir 'src/main/resources'compileClasspath = configurations.runtime + fileTree(dir:"$project.HOME_DIR/$project.SERVICE_NAME/lib", includes: ['*.jar'])
            }
    }
```

Comment: Why are you putting .properties and .csv in a folder named java? The src/main/java folder is for java sources only. I strongly suggest that you follow gradle (and maven's) sensible conventions and put these files in src/main/resources. It looks like these files should actually be in src/test/java and src/test/resources if they are for testing only.

Comment: Thanks Lance. Yes i can put them into resources folder. I have put the .csv files in the resources folder. But kept the .properties at the same place as .java files to avoid creating the same package structure in the resources folder. Also to see the files in the same place as .java files for easy viewing. In Maven, we can do this and ask Maven to include all the files during compilation using include tag. Wondering if similar thing is there for Gradle too. By the by, you are correct i have to put these files in src/test folder instead of src/main folder which i will do. Thanks for the info.

Comment: As I said, src/main/java and src/test/java are for java files ONLY. You can hack both maven and gradle to look for resources in these folders but you shouldn't. I'm not going to help you here because it's a bad idea. Use your tools... don't abuse them ;)

Comment: Tools are there to support developers, not the other way round. Sure it makes sense to understand why the defaults are as they are, but these tools are customisable precisely to allow developers to do things like this when they want/need to.

Answer (score 14):

Just add the required files to the default processResources task:

```
processResources {
  from ('src/main/java') {
    include '**/*.properties'
    include '**/*.csv'
  }
}
```